# highcharts - Draw horizontal line outside the chart area

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart as in the picture below. How do I draw a responsive horizontal line (and label) outside the chart area?

I know we could achieve something similar using `plotLines` and `plotBands` but the value has to be the one within the value range in the `series`, and the line won't be drawn outside the chart either.

In my case, I want to draw the line outside the chart area, specifically under the xAxis (see the line in red color).

Is there a way to do that?
[image]

```js
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('sd-median-annual-earnings-chart', {
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: null,
      style: {
        fontSize: 'inherit',
        overflow: 'visible',
        width: '100%'
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Median Annual Earnings',
      style: {
        color: '#000',
        fontFamily: 'inherit',
        fontSize: '1.2em',
        fontWeight: 700
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D'
      ],
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify',
        style: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      },
      tickWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 40000,
      gridLineColor: '#d6d6d6',
      title: {
        text: 'Percent',
        style: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          fontFamily: 'inherit',
          fontSize: 'inherit'
        }
      },
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify',
        style: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      },
      tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
        var each = Highcharts.each,
          ticks = [];

        for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
          if (i % 5000 === 0)
            ticks.push(i);
        }

        return ticks;
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      symbolRadius: 0,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#000'
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#86BC25'
      },
      itemMarginBottom: 5
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderColor: null,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000',
          format: "{y}",
          style: {
            textOutline: false
          }
        },
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function() {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      series: {
        groupPadding: 0.1
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'A',
      color: '#000',
      data: [10000, 34000, 25000, 6000]
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      color: 'blue',
      data: [5000, 4000, 10000, 20000]
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      color: '#046A38',
      data: [6000, 15000, 5000, 1500]
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      color: 'green',
      data: [8700, 12000, 7000, 15000]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sd-median-annual-earnings-chart" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></div>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Brianing/wtoy7L15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) to add line and text inside charts

[image]

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  backgroundColor: null,
  style: {
    fontSize: 'inherit',
    overflow: 'visible',
    width: '100%'
  },
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var ren = this.renderer,
        stline = ['M', 100, 0, 'L', 340, 0];

      ren.label('Label', this.chartWidth - 155, this.chartHeight - 50)
        .css({
          fontSize: '10px',
          color: '#FF0000'
        })
        .add();
      ren.path(stline)
        .attr({
          'stroke-width': 2,
          stroke: '#FF0000'
        })
        .translate(this.chartWidth - 360, this.chartHeight - 50)
        .add();
    }
  }
},
```

**Note works best on fixed sized containers**

```js
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('sd-median-annual-earnings-chart', {
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: null,
      style: {
        fontSize: 'inherit',
        overflow: 'visible',
        width: '100%'
      },
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var ren = this.renderer,
            stline = ['M', 100, 0, 'L', 340, 0];

          ren.label('Label', this.chartWidth - 155, this.chartHeight - 50)
            .css({
              fontSize: '10px',
              color: '#FF0000'
            })
            .add();
          ren.path(stline)
            .attr({
              'stroke-width': 2,
              stroke: '#FF0000'
            })
            .translate(this.chartWidth - 360, this.chartHeight - 50)
            .add();
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Median Annual Earnings',
      style: {
        color: '#000',
        fontFamily: 'inherit',
        fontSize: '1.2em',
        fontWeight: 700
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D'
      ],
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify',
        style: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      },
      tickWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 40000,
      gridLineColor: '#d6d6d6',
      title: {
        text: 'Percent',
        style: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          fontFamily: 'inherit',
          fontSize: 'inherit'
        }
      },
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify',
        style: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      },
      tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
        var each = Highcharts.each,
          ticks = [];

        for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
          if (i % 5000 === 0)
            ticks.push(i);
        }

        return ticks;
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      symbolRadius: 0,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#000'
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#86BC25'
      },
      itemMarginBottom: 5
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderColor: null,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000',
          format: "{y}",
          style: {
            textOutline: false
          }
        },
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function() {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      series: {
        groupPadding: 0.1
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'A',
      color: '#000',
      data: [10000, 34000, 25000, 6000]
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      color: 'blue',
      data: [5000, 4000, 10000, 20000]
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      color: '#046A38',
      data: [6000, 15000, 5000, 1500]
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      color: 'green',
      data: [8700, 12000, 7000, 15000]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sd-median-annual-earnings-chart" style="width: 600px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Deep 3015. How to make it responsive? That is my biggest challenge.

Comment: Looking great. Thank you. Using `this.chartHeight` and `this.chartWidth` works perfectly for the responsive part. I will replace `window.innerHeight` and `width.innerWidth` with `this.chartWidth` and `this.chartHeight` respectively in your jsfiddle code in the comment above.